# TableView in iCarousel finding nil while unwrapping optional value

Tags: swift, swift3, icarousel

So, I have a carousel of "BillSplitters" and on each carousel item it should display the uniques items a BillSplitter is having. So I'm getting `fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` Normally i can slowly hone in on an error like this i find the issue but when following on from a breakpoint line by line it enters into the iCarousel code which i cant follow. Im also sure theres nothing going wrong in i carousel as if i dont addSubview(tableView) then it runs fine. It also seems to create the first couple of tableviews and add them fine and then gets the error. Here is the code im using:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    let splitter = allBillSplitters[carouselIndex]
    if (splitter.items?.count)! > 0 {
        return (splitter.items?.count)!
    } else {
        TableViewHelper.EmptyMessage("\(splitter.name!) has no items to pay for.\nGo back to assign some items to their name.", tableView: tableView)
        return 0
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell: ItemCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SplitterItemCell") as! ItemCell
    let itemsSet = allBillSplitters[carouselIndex].items
    let items = itemsSet?.allObjects as! [Item]
    let item = items[indexPath.row]
    let count = item.billSplitters?.count
    if count! > 1 {
        cell.name!.text = "\(item.name!) split \(count!) ways"
        cell.price!.text = "£\(Double(item.price)/Double(count!))"
    } else {
        cell.name!.text = item.name!
        cell.price!.text = "£\(item.price)"
    }

    return cell
}

func numberOfItems(in carousel: iCarousel) -> Int {
    return allBillSplitters.count
}
```

I've read in a few places that I should remove the `if let view = view` statement in the following function as it's not re-using the items and always creating new ones. If I leave it in I get the same error immediately when creating the first carousel item and when I remove it, it happens on the creating the third i carousel item.

```
func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, viewForItemAt index: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {

    carouselIndex = index

    var splitterView: UIImageView
    var nameLabel: UILabel
    var emailLabel: UILabel
    var totalLabel: UILabel
    var tableView: UITableView

    let splitter = allBillSplitters[index]

    //reuse view if available, otherwise create a new view
    if let view = view as? UIImageView {
        splitterView = view
        //get a reference to the label in the recycled view
        nameLabel = splitterView.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
        emailLabel = splitterView.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
        totalLabel = splitterView.viewWithTag(3) as! UILabel
        tableView = splitterView.viewWithTag(4) as! UITableView
    } else {

        let height = carousel.contentView.frame.height - 85
        let width = carousel.contentView.frame.width - 80

        //don't do anything specific to the index within
        //this `if ... else` statement because the view will be
        //recycled and used with other index values later
        splitterView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))
        splitterView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        splitterView.clipsToBounds = true
        splitterView.image = UIImage(data: splitter.image as! Data, scale:1.0)
        splitterView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        splitterView.backgroundColor = UIColor(netHex: 0xCA9875)

        let viewWidth = Int(splitterView.frame.width)

        nameLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 5, y: 0, width: viewWidth, height: 30))
        nameLabel.backgroundColor = .clear
        nameLabel.backgroundColor?.withAlphaComponent(0.1)
        nameLabel.textAlignment = .left
        nameLabel.font = nameLabel.font.withSize(20)
        nameLabel.tag = 1

        emailLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 5, y: 30, width: viewWidth, height: 15))
        emailLabel.backgroundColor = .clear
        emailLabel.textAlignment = .left
        emailLabel.font = emailLabel.font.withSize(15)
        emailLabel.tag = 2

        totalLabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 5, y: 45, width: viewWidth, height: 15))
        totalLabel.backgroundColor = .clear
        totalLabel.textAlignment = .left
        totalLabel.font = totalLabel.font.withSize(15)
        totalLabel.tag = 3

        let tableViewHeight = height - 65
        let frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 65, width: width, height: tableViewHeight)
        tableView = UITableView(frame: frame)
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.tag = 4
        totalLabel.backgroundColor = .clear

        splitterView.addSubview(nameLabel)
        splitterView.addSubview(emailLabel)
        splitterView.addSubview(totalLabel)
        splitterView.addSubview(tableView)
    }

    //set item label
    //remember to always set any properties of your carousel item
    //views outside of the `if (view == nil) {...}` check otherwise
    //you'll get weird issues with carousel item content appearing
    //in the wrong place in the carousel
    nameLabel.text = "\(allBillSplitters[index].name!)"
    emailLabel.text = "\(allBillSplitters[index].email!)"
    totalLabel.text = "£\(allBillSplitters[index].total)"


    return splitterView
}

func carousel(_ carousel: iCarousel, valueFor option: iCarouselOption, withDefault value: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    switch option {
    case .spacing:
        return value * 1.2
    case .fadeMin:
        return 0.0
    case .fadeMinAlpha:
        return 0.3
    case .fadeMax:
        return 0.0
    default:
        return value
    }
}
```

I've looked all over and can't find a solution so any help would be great. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm an idiot. Forgot the following:

```
tableView.register(CarouselTableViewCell.classForCoder(), forCellReuseIdentifier: "carouselTableViewCell")
```

in tableviews cellForRowAt function